# Adding a 3D object into a UIKit based app (SceneKit, GLKit..?)

Tags: ios, 3d, shader, glkit

I need to add a 3D cube that the user could rotate into an iOS app with classic functionalities such as navigation and tab bar; it would be great to render it with custom shaders in order to have a cartoon style.

Which is a simple way to achieve it?
Would SceneKit or GLKit be a good solution?
Is it possible to integrate a 3D object into a view of a UIKit based app?

Thanks a lot for any hint,
DAN

Comment: SceneKit is not available for iOS. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, so GLKit could be a good solution..